# US bill traceable?

Tags: united-states, banking

In my country (France) we have to be registered before changing € to $ USD with names, address etc... Is a US bill traceable? Can the authorities know with the serial number were the bill went, in which countries, and the name of the person who took the bill? Is the bill registered at a foreign country's border? I'm in foreign law college in France; we talked about money but not this kind of stuff and my teacher can't help me.

Comment: It isn't really clear to me what this question has to do with law.

Comment: Sure, anyone can put a U.S. bill serial in at http://www.wheresgeorge.com/

Answer (score 1):

Bills can be traced and limited information about their history may be available if you have a bill--for example, you may discover when it was printed.  In addition, some money counting machines will scan the serial numbers of money that is counted, and cash used for a ransom, for example, may have its serial numbers tracked.  However, serial numbers are generally not tracked if a consumer simply takes a bill across a border.  The authorities would need to scan every dollar bill, and that would be annoying and largely a waste of their time.

Comment: If SWIM had money dumped in their account by a third party and afterwards the third party made a 'joke' about how it's Russian Mob money but it's already been spent... if I had a funny feeling the money had bad vibes attached (it made SWIM have a minor cardiac infarction when it arrived) at the time, so kept it attached to a limited company entity, but the money was also attached to an email account bearing SWIM's name... does that have anything to do with this question at all?

Comment: Not on the facts presented.  "Money dumped in their account" can mean a lot of things.  Some of them will trigger anti-money-laundering laws in various countries.  In addition, if a homicide or organized crime is involved you will find substantially higher interest in tracking money from various government and intergovernmental organizations, including activities that happen far away from the public radar as intelligence services try to trace money that may fund terrorism, etc... It is a very different question than simply asking whether cash bills are tracked at a border.

Comment: If you have concerns about whether the source of funds in your control is legitimate, you are welcome to consult with a person licensed to practice law in your jurisdiction.

Comment: See also https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/law-enforcement